# C игнорирует цикл, не заходит в 2 цикл for

Tags: c, циклы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void) {
   int number;
  do
  {
      printf("print your number here: ");
      scanf("%d", &number);
   }
   while ( number > 23 );
   printf ("here is your number, %d\n", number);
         for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
            printf("second_for");
            for (int j = 0; j > i; j++ ) {
               printf("1213");
            }
            printf("\n");
       }
}
```

Вот код (скрин консоли):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит сочетание слов "не заходит в 2 цикл for"? Что такое "в 2 цикл for"?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У вас странное условие (`j > i`) внутреннего цикла (крутить цикл, пока `j` строго больше `i`, хотя ещё на первой итерации `j == 0, i > 1 => j > i`).

Answer (score 2):

У вас постоянно J меньше чем I, а условие цикла составлено наоборот, поэтому не заходит в цикл.